# In React ,aside from 'useState' Hook which hooks would would be most useful and why?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React now I just wanted to know which hooks would be most use full as a react developer

I am learning useEffect hook but I don't understand when and how should they be used and how the other hooks will be use full.

Comment: Hi , You can find all the info regarding hooks here - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

useEffect will be the most important one after useState. You can take action when the props or state variables change. For instance:

```
  const [active, setIsActive] = useState();

  useEffect(()=>{
    // this will run once when the component mounts.
    setIsActive(true)
  },[]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    // this will run everytime that props change
  },[props]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    return () => {
      // this will run when the component unmont
      setIsActive(false)
    }
  },[]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    // this will run everytime the component is called.
  });
```

You can find more information in the docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html
But that should be the lifecycle.